# shrinking set of buttons when minimizing page css - html

Tags: html, css

I have a set of buttons in html:

```
<div class="controls">
  <div id="s-controls">
    <button class="control-btn" style="background-color: #2de7f6">1</button>
    <button class="control-btn" style="background-color: #69a6ea">2</button>
    <button class="control-btn" style="background-color: #736ace">3</button>
    <button class="control-btn" style="background-color: #372ac3">4</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

that I want to shrink when minimizing the page. Right now when doing that, the buttons mantain their size and the design looks messy.

I have tried many things with css but I am not really good at it. This is what I have so far:

```
.controls {
 background-color: #1F1F1F; 
 min-height: 50px;
}

button {
 margin: 20px auto;
 max-width: 100%; 
}

#s-controls, #p-controls {
 text-align: center;
}

#s-controls > *, #p-controls > * {
 font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
 font-weight: 600;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.control-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  /*border-radius: 4px;*/
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  line-height: 2.5em;
  padding: 0 3em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

 line-height: 1.75em;
  padding: 0 0.75em; 
 }

 .control-btn:hover { 
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), 
   inset 0 1.5em 1em rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 }
```

I intend to do this in pure html and css. The idea is to shrink the buttons at some point that they mantain the original one row design.

Any help would be appreciatted!

Comment: Try using percentages for the width and height of the buttons. e.g. `width: 50%` Also, the [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) CSS framework might make your static web design work easier. Do check it out.

Comment: What do you mean by "minimizing the page"?

Comment: @AkshayDamle I'm trying to solve things without a framework so I can learn the basics. But this is driving me nuts

Comment: @Rokin when you resize the browser page

Comment: do the buttons have to be equal in width?

Comment: @razzak not necessarily. It depends on the button's name. Some can be for explample: "play", "fast forward" and so on

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a width for the all of the containers (#s-controls, div.controls), and setting the actual width for the buttons, not just the max-width.

```
div.controls { width: 100%; }

#s-controls { width: 100%; }

button { width: 100%; max-width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

For different devices alignments you can use media query. For example for mobile width I have added button **{width: 100% !important;}** so that it will not collapse..

Please let me know if you are not looking for this

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    button {
  padding: 0 2em !important;
}
  }

controls {
 background-color: #1F1F1F; 
 min-height: 50px;
}

button {
 margin: 20px auto;
 max-width: 100%; 
}

#s-controls, #p-controls {
 text-align: center;
}

#s-controls > *, #p-controls > * {
 font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
 font-weight: 600;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.control-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  /*border-radius: 4px;*/
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  line-height: 2.5em;
  padding: 0 3em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

 line-height: 1.75em;
  padding: 0 0.75em; 
 }

 .control-btn:hover { 
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), 
   inset 0 1.5em 1em rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 }
```

```html
<div class="controls">
  <div id="s-controls">
    <button class="control-btn" style="background-color: #2de7f6">1</button>
    <button class="control-btn" style="background-color: #69a6ea">2</button>
    <button class="control-btn" style="background-color: #736ace">3</button>
    <button class="control-btn" style="background-color: #372ac3">4</button>
  </div>
</div>

.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my idea is not to re position the buttons but to make them so small the even fit in the minimized page in one row (original design)

Comment: code has been changed. for Small devices in media query you can change the padding of the button to 0.2em. Above code will work for you i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Using media queries will give you the manipulation you are looking for at different devices and/or shrinking your browser.

Do this for all widths you are looking for and adjust the padding accordingly:

```
@media (max-width:991px){ //change this number to 768px, 560px, 480px, etc
   .control-btn {
      padding: 0 2em;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to add `nowrap` to the container for buttons:

```
#s-controls { white-space: nowrap; }
```

but you also need to define button width:

```
.control-btn {
  max-width: 90px;
  width: 24%;
}
```

You can play with those values to fine-tune them.

Also, you have an extra closing curly bracket in `.control-btn` that messes up the code. Delete it.

```
  padding: 0 3em;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* } extra bracket */
  line-height: 1.75em;
  padding: 0 0.75em;
```

See it in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8joje7q8/)

Comment: pretty accurate, one thing is that my buttons have names which are much longer in characters than numbers. When I use your method, the button's names does not shrink with the button

Comment: also the grey background doesn't resize either